# Database access with threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite

I'm developing a program (using C++ running on a Linux machine) that uses SQLite as a back-end.

It has 2 threads which carry out the following tasks:

- **Thread 1**

  - Waits for a piece of data to arrive (in this case, via a radio module)
  - Immediately inserts it into the database
  - Returns to waiting for new data
  - It is important this thread is "listening" for as much of the time as possible and isn't blocked waiting to insert into the database
- **Thread 2**

  - Every 2 minutes, runs a SELECT on the database to find un-processed data
  - Processes the data
  - UPDATEs the rows fetched with a flag to show they have been processed

The key thing is to make sure that Thread 1 can always INSERT into the database, even if this means that Thread 2 is unable to SELECT or UPDATE (as this can just take place at a future point, the timing isn't critical).

I was hoping to find a way to prioritise INSERTs somehow using SQLite, but have failed to find a way so far. Another thought was for Thread 1 to push it's the data into a basic queue (held in memory) and then bulk INSERT it every so often (as this wouldn't be blocking the receiving of data and could do a simple check to see if the database was locked, if so, wait a few milliseconds and try again).

However, what is the "proper" way to do this with SQLite and C++ threads?

Comment: Does the API you are using to communicate to the DB support asynchronous calls?

Comment: Don't use thread 1 to insert into the database - use an in-memory queue and insert it from thread 1a.  Re: multi-threading see https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm exploring the queue option. Seems like that might be the most scalable version for the situation if the volume of data increases

Answer (score 0):

SQlite database can be opened with or without multi-threading support. Both threads should open the database  separately. 
If you want to do the hard way, you can use a priority queue and process the queries.

Comment: Thanks. Finding it hard to work out how to check if the DB has been compiled with multi-thread support. If I try to use it with the sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD); command, we're getting a memory error. I'm also exploring the queue idea too.